# RMySQL wrong quote escaping

Tags: mysql, r

I'm using R with RMySQL library to connect to Mysql database.

I have seen there is a problem with their escaping function:

```
> dbEscapeStrings(con, "HE''LLO")
[1] "HE\\'\\'LLO"
```

this is wrong, It should be: `"He\'\'LLO"`

Do I have to use another function to escape quotes and double quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mistaking the printed R representation with the actual result from `dbEscapeStrings()`. In R `\` also needs to be escaped. So if you want a literal `\`, you need two of them `\\`. This is how the escaped string is displayed by R when printing and explains the observed behaviour:

```
> foo <- dbEscapeStrings(con, "HE''LLO")
> foo
[1] "HE\\'\\'LLO"
```

However, note that this is just the way that escaped string is represented within R at the console. If we `cat()` or `writeLines()` the escaped string to the console, instead of `print()`-ing

```
> writeLines(foo)
HE\'\'LLO
```

we see that it has been properly escaped. The latter is how MySQL would see it.